# how to set a custom location, rotation and scale size for an object once shortcut button is pressed?

Tags: python

In the following post, I learned how to create cubes of the size I want.

[how to set a custom scale size for an object once shortcut button is pressed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231286/how-to-set-a-custom-scale-size-for-an-object-once-shortcut-button-is-pressed?rq=1)

```
def draw(self, context):
    object = context.object
    layout = self.layout 
    
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add").scale=(1, 1, 1)
```

I used this code to add an additional location and rotation value.
However, it does not work

I want to add position, scale and rotation values to the row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add") code.

Here's the code:

```
def draw(self, context):
    object = context.object
    layout = self.layout 
    
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add").location=(0, 0, 5), rotation=(0, 0, 10), scale=(1, 1, 1)
```

======================== Add ===========================

[How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-pass-multiple-operator-properties-via-ui-layout)

brockmann's answer in the next post is the way I want it to be.

I write it down as below, and all functions work fine.

I want to write the rotation value in one line like location or scale, but I do not know how to write it, so I wrote it in 3 lines.

Thank you brockmann!

```
import bpy
import math
.
.
.

    def draw(self, context):
        object = context.object
        layout = self.layout 
        
        row = layout.row()
        props = row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        props.enter_editmode=False
        props.location = (0, 0, 5)
        props.rotation[0] = math.radians(0)
        props.rotation[1] = math.radians(0)
        props.rotation[2] = math.radians(10)
        props.scale = (1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of "does not work"?  Do you get a python exception / error, or are the specified location and rotation overridden?

Comment: There are many Sidebars that I am using, and I have registered this script in one of them and am using it.
But when I put that code, the sidebar doesn't appear for some reason.
Errors are usually checked in INFO, but no text is shown.

Comment: `props.rotation = (math.radians(0), math.radians(1), math.radians(2))` should do the trick, see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=primitive_cube_add#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add ((float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf], (optional)))

Comment: Thank you brockmann!  May I ask you one more thing?
I wonder if it is possible to create a cube by specifying the name I want when creating a cube.

Comment: If you'd like to use `primitive_cube_add()`, answer is no ([click  here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=primitive_cube_add#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add)). Otherwise you'd have to use the Bmesh module: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh#module-bmesh How to create a cube using Bmesh has already been explained over here -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63546/create-a-cube-in-blender-from-python and there are a lot of high quality Q&A's, just search for it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=bmesh